# How would I create a 95% confidence interval with log-transformed data?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I have data for insulate material and fail times and need to create a 95% confidence interval for the mean failure of each material. However the data is log-transformed because the residuals were not normal with the original data. How do I use this data to find intervals for the original data?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what exactly you are seeking the confidence interval of? If you take the approach tersely suggested below, i.e. calculate a confidence interval on the logarithm and then back transform, you will have a confidence interval for the median (or geometric mean) on the original scale. If you want the confidence interval for the mean, you will have to use a different estimator, which is only trivially more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

In the same way that you would compute and other confidence interval:

1. Transform data to the log you want
2. Calculate the mean of the transformed data
3. Calculate the standard error of the transformed data
4. Compute the upper and lower bounds, with the choosen confidence level

I might add that you dont need the residuals (from regression I assume?) to be normal, in order to calculate the confidence band. Assuming you have a large sample.

Comment: The obtained intervals won't be symmetric anymore. That probably motivated the OP to raise the issue here. Is there any method to remedy the asymmetry?